# Multiple HTML tables from one array (PHP)

Tags: php, foreach

I have one array of elements with "Segment ID" and "Account ID". I would like to print multiple HTML tables for each Segment and each Account.

**Array:**

id 1 | Item 10 | Segment 1 | Account 1

id 2 | Item 15 | Segment 1 | Account 1

id 3 | Item 11 | Segment 2 | Account 1

id 4 | Item 16 | Segment 2 | Account 2

Would print out 3 tables

**Result:**

Table 1 (id 1 and 2)

Table 2 (id 3)

Table 3 (id 4)

Can this be done with nested foreach loops?
Sorry for bad representation. I have no idea how to print a readable array in this editor.

**Edit:**
Some code if it helps:

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Product ID</th>
     <th>Segment ID</th>
     <th>Account ID</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>{{ $order->ProductId }}</td>
     <td>{{ $order->SegmentId }}</td>
     <td>{{ $order->AccountId }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
@endforeach
```

So this would give 1 table with all elements.

I would like to get multiple HTML tables. Foreach SegmentId and foreach AccountId.

Comment: The short answer is yes but without seeing your data we'd be guessing if we tried to help. Show us what you've attempted already that isn't working the way you want/need it to.

Comment: This can be done with `array_chunk` and couple of foreach loops. But the problem is the way you need to chunk the array doesn't have a pattern

Answer (score 0):

Splitt the Arrays for your needs

```
id 1 | Item 10 | Segment 1 | Account 1

id 2 | Item 15 | Segment 1 | Account 1

id 3 | Item 11 | Segment 2 | Account 1

id 4 | Item 16 | Segment 2 | Account 2
```

surgesst you have an array like this

```
$array = array('id'=>1,'item'=>10,'segment'=>1,'account'=>1)....
```

you can do it (out of the box) like this

```
$tables = array();
foreach($array as $arr) {
   $segment = $arr['segment'];
   $account = $arr['account'];
   $tables[$segment][$account][] = $arr; //UPDATE [] for multiparts
}
```

now you have in $tables your prefered ordering and then you can go on like this

```
foreach($tables as $segment=>$arr) {
   foreach($arr as $account=>$yourdata) {
      echo "<table><tr>...</tr></table>";
   }
}
```

Comment: You suggest I make multidimensional array?

Comment: you post you have a multidemensional array ... ;)

Comment: i only can suggest ... you didn't post what the array data is you have

Comment: You got me on the right track :) I get multiple tables now. But only with one element each. (the last element foreach segment/account)